# Gauss plane and vector module calculation

Tags: vector-spaces, vector-analysis

Ok guys, let's say that I have this vector:

[image]

Why, when I calculate the modulus of this vector, I get $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$, and not $\sqrt{a^2+(b\operatorname{i})^2}$. When I do the calculation in the first way  I neglet $\operatorname{i}$, that is a part of a cathetus.
If **i** is a part of a cathetus why neglet it?

Comment: you are using the Pythagorean theorem  and the lengths of the two sides are $a,b$ so we use $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ and not $\sqrt{a^2+(bi)^2}$

Comment: @The Integrator First of all thanks for your help, second: but the lenghts of one cathetus is bi, not just b.I can't understand this thing.

Comment: No, the length is $b$. A length is a real number. Just try it: put a ruler on the paper and measure the distance between the points $a$ and $a+bi$, and you will see that it measures $b$ units of lenght.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that is confusing you  , you can also define the modulus $|z| $ as ;

$|z| = \sqrt{z\cdot \bar z}\qquad$$\qquad$ where $\bar z $ is the complex conjugate of $z$

let $z =a + ib$

$\bar z = a-ib$

$|z| = \sqrt{(a+ib)(a-ib)}$

$|z| = \sqrt{a^2-iab+iab-(ib)^2}$

$|z| = \sqrt{a^2-i^2\cdot b^2}$

$|z| = \sqrt{a^2+b^2}$

Comment: YOU ARE A GENIUS!!!!!!!!!THANKS A LOT!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @A.Rossi i am not one, Just happy to help others understand

Comment: @ The Integrator NONO, YOU ARE A GENIUS!!!